# WildFly 10.0 port offset "9" can't connect to CLI at 9999

Tags: port, wildfly, offset, wildfly-10

I need to run a WildFly 10.0.0 instance with a jboss.socket.binding.port-offset=9

It start but I'm not able to connect to CLI with port 9999 (9990+offset)

Comment: What does boot log says about listening address?

Comment: 2018-12-10 15:17:27,335 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9999/management
    2018-12-10 15:17:27,336 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9999
    2018-12-10 15:17:27,337 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) started in 3215ms - Started 267 of 553 services (371 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)  <br/> @ctomc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use port 9999, CLI will by default fallback to remoting protocol (EAP 6 default) and won't be able to connect to the EAP 7 although the correct port number is used. Because of this, you have to use protocol while connecting to remote server instance, like as:

`$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --controller=http-remoting://localhost:9999`